# What should I be aware of when opening a Lenovo X201 to look at the fan?

Tags: laptop, fan, cooling, disassembly

My Lenovo X201's fan has been making a lot of noise on occasion recently (buzzing, sawing even); also, I've been getting shut-downs due to max temperature reached, although not at the same time as the noisy fan.

So, I was thinking of trying to open it up and having a look - at the fan at least - as suggested in answers on noisy fan questions.

Now, I want to be super-careful here, so:

- Do I need any special tools/implements other than the appropriate-size screwdriver?
- Is there any glue in there which I will need to undo?
- Anything special to watch out for?

I'm also not sure how to clean the fan or to determine whether the fan noise is related to the power-downs, but I guess that should go on a different question, unless there's some "pick your laptop apart guide" which covers all that.

Notes:

- A while ago I upgraded my Laptop memory to 2 x 4GB instead of 1 x 2GB; it used to be much slower before but didn't have power-outs.

Comment: Your best bet would be to Google for a service manual, or even a user take-apart.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Tetsujin's suggestion, this seems to cover the basics:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJZZSD8x9_8

It's a step-by-step video of disassembling the X201 and examining the fan.

Comment: Also [Hardware Maintenance Manual](https://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/x200_x200s_x200si_x201_x201i_x201s_hmm_en_43y6632_11.pdf)